Checking on a 3 minute delta of a timestamp at 30 minute boundary
I have a spring-boot scheduler that wakes up every 15 minutes. It is a cron, so it will always wake up around proper boundary with some jitter but is usually around 00, 15, 30, 45, 60.
I need to do the below:

Do some action A for 30 minute boundary only if at wakeup, delta is within 3 minute range on either side. So around 11:00am do action A only if time is around 10:57-11:03. Similar for the 30 minute boundary, do it if delta is around 10:57-11:03 or 11:27-11:33

I am reading time as below when scheduler wakes up
ZonedDateTime currentDate = (ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES));
ZonedDateTime prior = currentDate.minus(3,ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
ZonedDateTime next = currentDate.plus(3,ChronoUnit.MINUTES);

I am familiar I can add and subtract to get the window as above. But where I am getting lost is the trivial part of how do I compare of the time is within the prior and next boundary?
Because if the scheduler woke up at 11:35, I do not wish to take the action for 11:30 and skip processing.

No check if your currentDate isBefore next and isAfter prior, (currentDate.isBefore(next) && currentDate.isAfter(prior))

tl;dr
int minute = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ).getMinute() ;  // Capture the current moment as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from temporal meridian of UTC. Then extract the minute of the time-of-day.
if ( minute >= 57 || minute <= 3 ) { … do action A … }           // OR logic for hour wraparound.
else if ( minute >= 27 && minute <= 33 ) { … }                   // AND logic for a range of minutes within the hour.

Details
Your code:

ZonedDateTime currentDate = (ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES));

… uses an inappropriate class.
For a mere offset (UTC) rather than a time zone, use OffsetDateTime rather than ZonedDateTime.
OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;

You said:

So around 11:00am do action A only if time is around 10:57-11:03.

Extract the minute.
int minute = now.getMinute() ;

Test for your desired range. Use OR logic because of the one hour cutover.
if ( minute >= 57 || minute <= 3 ) { … do action A … }

You might want to add parentheses for clarity there. But not necessary. According to Java operator precedence, the <=/>= tests come before the AND/OR (&&/||) logic.
You said:

Similar for the 30 minute boundary, do it if delta is around 10:57-11:03 or 11:27-11:33

Similar to above, but change the test from OR to AND.
if ( minute >= 27 && minute <= 33 ) { … }

You said:

if the scheduler woke up at 11:35, I do not wish to take the action for 11:30

The logic above does that. A minute of 35 fails both tests, so no action taken.

But that won't exactly address what I am looking for. If scheduler kicked in at 58th minute, I still want it to trigger action A for the 30 minute boundary

@curiousengineer Your Comment contradicts your Question. See the last quote I pulled from your Question.

@curiousengineer "If scheduler kicked in at 58th minute, I still want it to trigger action A for the 30 minute boundary" - it will! minute >= 57 || minute <= 3 will be true so the action will be performed.

I'd probably use Basil's method, but here's an alternative to add some interest. My method works for arbitrary differences, not necessarily an exact amount of minutes.
    // Clock that ticks at half-hourly intervals, returning the current
    // time to the nearest half hour.
    private static final Clock clockTicking30Minutes = Clock.tick(
            Clock.offset(Clock.systemUTC(), Duration.ofMinutes(15)),
            Duration.ofMinutes(30));

    public void myScheduledMethod() {
        Instant nowToNearest30Minutes = Instant.now(clockTicking30Minutes);
        Instant nowExact = Instant.now();
        Duration difference = Duration.between(nowExact, nowToNearest30Minutes).abs();
        if (difference.compareTo(Duration.ofMinutes(3)) <= 0) {
            // Do task A
        }
    }



Thanks. Read the comment in your reply but wondering why are you doing an offset of 15 minutes. I do have a scheduler that wakes up at 15 minute boundaries but of course there can be a jitter.

The offset of 15 minutes is just so the clock gives you the time rounded to the nearest half hour; otherwise it would show the time truncated to the previous half hour. The Clock.tick method truncates, so if the time is, say, 9:46, you want it to say 10:00. By adding 15 minutes, you get 10:01 and that then gets truncated to 10:00.

Can you give an example on why it would go to previous hour? I am sorry if it sounds silly to you

It would be truncated to the previous half hour. If you just have clock = Clock.tick(Clock.systemUTC(), Duration.ofMinutes(30)) and the current time is 9:59:59, then Instant.now(clock) would give you 9:30:00.
